# Jetty daemon and useTestClasspath, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Since I'm trying to set an embded container in my maven project I want to it run during the integration test phase. I have two problems with jetty that I can not manage to resolve :

1. `<daemon>true</daemon>` doesn't have the expected effect. The server is run but then it locks the build process (in fact it blocks the unit tests). **So where am I supposed to place that configuration ?**
2. The `<useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>` is a mystery for me. I don't want to use the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` to place the postgresql jar (which is called by jetty for the datasource (postegresql-driver)) because it would be embeded in the application and I don't want it to be in the war (client side). So I want to use `<useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>` but when I place postgresql in the `src/test/resources` it doesn't find/recognize it. **So, how am I supposed to use that property ?**

Here is the complete plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                        <contextPath>agepro-prototype</contextPath>
                        <webApp>
                            ${project.build.directory}/agepro-prototype.war
                        </webApp>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9091</port> 
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <stopPort>9092</stopPort>
                <stopKey>test</stopKey>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance for the help you could provide me. I must apologize for my grammar, because my english is quite bad.
Regards,
*Depado*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your first question, but as for your second, specify the postgresql jar as provided scope in your main dependency block (this will prevent it from being bundled in the war), and add an additional dependency block in the jetty plugin definition (with compile scope), which will make the postgresql jar available at jetty runtime:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-jetty</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run-war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <daemon>true</daemon>
                    <contextPath>agepro-prototype</contextPath>
                    <webApp>
                        ${project.build.directory}/agepro-prototype.war
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <connectors>
                <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                    <port>9091</port> 
                </connector>
            </connectors>
            <stopPort>9092</stopPort>
            <stopKey>test</stopKey>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> I don't want to use the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib to place the postgresql jar (which is called by jetty for the datasource (postegresql-driver)) because it would be embeded in the application and I don't want it to be in the war (client side). So I want to use true but when I place postgresql in the src/test/resources it doesn't find/recognize it

You shouldn't be placing jars in any folders (src/main/resources or src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes), they should all be defined as dependencies in your pom.

I also imagine the useTestClasspath is being ignored when you define the webApp configuration element, as the it's using the packaged war, which will not contain your test resources / classes

Comment: The only problem I got is that Postgresql is used on the server side of the application and I want to test the client side. So postgresql is declared in my pom but it's in the main scope and not in the test scope. I'm trying the code you sent here.
It works fine ! Thanks a lot ! Now I'm trying to run the jetty container and not block the rest of the lifecycle. The `<daemon>true</daemon>` seems not to work.

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing - one difference i see in your pom is the use of the run-war goal, rather than the run goal as specified in the above article - can see why it would make a difference, but might be worth a try?

Comment: Already tried that. I tried run, run-war, deploy-war (but didn't work because of my version of jetty), and it's still blocking my lifecycle. The selenium plugin and it's property `<background>` works fine... I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

useTestClasspath/useTestScope are only available for jetty:run

This is why it doesn't work with jetty:run-war and other jetty:goals